# DLL injection using C crash notepad

Tags: c, dll-injection

I created a DLL injector program using C and a DLL. When I am trying to run the program the target process crash (I tried a notepad and cmd). I am compiling the injector as 64 bit and the DLL as well. the program and the DLL compiled with Visual Studio.

After some checks a saw if I remove the `CreateRemoteThread` The program will not crash, and the DLL injected (of course without executing the DLL).

I tried to use `RUNDLL32.exe` to check if the DLL is the problem and I have been able to see the message box.

Injector:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    // The DLL path we want to inject and the target process id.
    LPCSTR dllpath = "C:\\Users\\....\\hello-world.dll";
    int processID = 2980;

    printf("#### Starting ####\n");

    // Open target process handle    
    HANDLE hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, processID);
    if (hProcess == NULL) {

        //close handles
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        printf("[!] Unable to find the target process id: %d\n" , processID);
        return 1;
    }
    printf("[+] Open target process handle\n");

    // Getting targt memory address for the dll path
    LPVOID dllpathMemoryAddr = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, strlen(dllpath) + 1, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_RESERVE, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (dllpathMemoryAddr == NULL) {

        //close handles
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        printf("[!] Unable to get memory address of target process for the dllpath");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("[+] Allocate the memory address to store the dllpath\n");

    // Writing the dll path to the target memory address
    BOOL succeedWrite = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dllpathMemoryAddr, dllpath, strlen(dllpath) + 1, NULL);
    if (!succeedWrite) {

        //close handles
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        printf("[!] Unable to write to the memory address of target process the dllpath\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("[+] Writed the dllpath to memory\n");

    // Getting LoadLibreryA address
    FARPROC loadLibAddr = 
        (GetModuleHandle(TEXT("kernel32.dll")), "LoadLibraryA");
    if (loadLibAddr == NULL) {
        // free the memory 
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllpathMemoryAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

        //close handles
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        printf("[!] Unable to get the memory address of LoadLibraryA function\n");
        return 1;
    }
    printf("[+] Allocate the memory address to LoadLibraryA function\n");

    // Create remote thread on the remote process to load the dll
    HANDLE rThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)loadLibAddr, dllpathMemoryAddr, 0, NULL);
    if (rThread == NULL) {
        // free the memory 
        VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllpathMemoryAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

        //close handles
        CloseHandle(hProcess);

        printf("[!] Unable to create thread to execute the LoadLibraryA function\n the error: %u\n", GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    printf("[+] Created remote thread to execute the dll\n");
    // Waiting to opertion to complete
    WaitForSingleObject(rThread, INFINITE);

    // free the memory 
    VirtualFreeEx(hProcess, dllpathMemoryAddr, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

    //close handles
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    CloseHandle(rThread);

    printf("#### DLL INJECTED ####\n");


    return TRUE;
}
```

DLL

```
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" __declspec(dllexport)
BOOL APIENTRY DllMain(HMODULE hModule,
                      DWORD ul_reason_for_call,
                      LPVOID lpReserved) {
  switch (ul_reason_for_call) {
    case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      MessageBox(NULL, "Hello world!", "Hello World!", NULL);
      break;
    case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
    case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
    case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
      break;
  }
  return TRUE;
}
```

output:

```
#### Starting ####
[+] Open target process handle
[+] Allocate the memory address to store the dllpath
[+] Writed the dllpath to memory
[+] Allocate the memory address to LoadLibraryA function
[+] Created remote thread to execute the dll
#### DLL INJECTED ####
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205402/discussion-on-question-by-gilad-di-castro-dll-injection-using-c-crash-notepad).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand the comments of the OP correctly, the main problem was that the OP had originally used the following line (before editing the question):

`BOOL succeedWrite = WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, dllpathMemoryAddr, dllpath, strlen(dllpath), NULL);`

By writing `strlen(dllpath)` instead of `strlen(dllpath) + 1` bytes, the OP did not write the terminating null character of the string into the remote process. Therefore, the remote process likely crashed when that non-terminated string was passed as a function parameter to `LoadLibraryA`.

As pointed out in the comments section, there were also some other problems with the code, but it is unlikely that these were the cause of the crash.